# Anisble script to restart services if failed

Tags: ansible, rundeck

Hope someone can help. I am just finding my feet in the world of Ansible and trying to create a script that checks if a service is running and if it is not started then start it. This is what I have so far. I am not sure if correct or not.

```yaml
---
  - hosts: all
    tasks:
      - name: Domain controller checks
        block:
          - name: Check Active Directory Domain Services are running
            become_method: runas
            win_service:
              name: "{{ item }}"
              start_mode: auto
              state: started  
            loop:
              - NTDS
              - ADWS
              - Dfs
              - DFSR
              - DNS
              - Kdc
      tasks:         
          - name: Restart failed services if needed
            failure_actions:
            - type: restart
              delay_ms: 5000
```

When running this script via rundeck I get the following error:

```
[WARNING]: While constructing a mapping from<br />
<br />/etc/ansible/scripts/Service_ChecksV2.yml, line 2, column 5, found a duplicate
dict key (tasks). Using last defined value only.<br />
<br />ERROR! unexpected parameter type in action: <class 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleSequence'><br />
<br />The error appears to be in '/etc/ansible/scripts/Service_ChecksV2.yml': line 20, column 13, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.<br />
<br />The offending line appears to be:
    <br />tasks:
          - name: Restart failed services if needed
            ^ here
Failed: AnsibleNonZero: ERROR: Ansible execution returned with non zero code.<br />
```

Comment: Please take note that according the error message: "_`found a duplicate dict key (tasks). Using last defined value only`_", there is a (kind of) typo. It will be necessary to remove at least the second occurrence of the playbook keyword `tasks`.

Comment: This is not a valid playbook, and you have something that looks like a  task definition using an non-existing module. Please have a look at the [`win_service` documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_service_module.html) and the examples on that page. I suspect what you are trying to write is [this](https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/f00dcc3c9ece777aeb03dc475ebe8e21) but I can't really tell since there are too many problems in your example code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ansible_facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/service_facts_module.html#service-facts-module) module to check for the running services.

The implementation would be as following:

```
# load service facts
- name: Prepare service facts
  service_facts:
```

You can then run your task to restart a service with the when variable

```
when: ansible_facts.services["Dfs.service"]["state"] != "running"
```

Comment: You don't need to check if a service is running prior to describing its expected state is started. `win_service` is idempotent and will start the service only if needed.

Comment: Just to clarify after your edit: there is absolutely no need to load `service_facts` to fulfill OP's requirement. Loading service facts is slow and should be done only if you really need them (e.g. check that a service exists to condition some other task...). One example: check that a firewall service is installed/activated/running to play a task that will open a port else don't do anything. There is absolutely no need to do such a thing here from the information we have. I linked an example in my comment right below the question which should do the job (If OP confirms his intent).

Comment: @Zeitounator thank you pointing me in the right direction, I will take a look over this. All of this is new and trying to pick up a new skill so all the help is appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your script is failing due to extra `tasks` section in the playbook.

And as per your requriement , in first section `state: started` is suffice.
As it will look for service status, if ansible found service as running then it will not do anything. otherwise if it found service not running then it will start the service.